# How do I get PRIMARY KEY from database using another column's value? (Android, SQLite)

Tags: android, sqlite

I've got a table with id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT column and NAME VARCHAR column. And I know the value of the NAME column.

How do I retrieve id of the row that contains the value?

Comment: In the future, we welcome any valid programming question, provided that you've [done your research](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my SQLite is rusty, but something along these lines should work:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE name IS myVar
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `ContentProvider`, you would do something along the lines of

```
getContentResolver().query(CONTENT_URI, null, "name_col = ?", new String[] { "name" }, null);
```

Comment: Thanks, i've just started learning android and so far I prefer using simple things and after a while i'll touch upon a contentprovider.

Comment: ContentProvider is the proper way to handle contacts and media within Android.  Definitely learn it. :)

Comment: It's also easier to use once you get used to it, in my opinion. It allows you to make use of the `LoaderManager` class too :).